# Can I start a standalone instance of JMS MQ Server for testing?

Tags: ibm-mq

Java.

I had to port away from the Proton MQ library to the IBM one. I had written a dummy MQ server to run jUnit tests against but I cannot see any way to achieve something similar with IBM MQ. To me it seems that it requires a standalone server and a license. Is that the case? Are there any lightweight alternatives usable for jUnit?

They mention that there is an IVTRun application which is actually just a wrapper over MQJMSIVT.class. Decompiling inside, I don't see anything that can start an actual server/queue manager. See this: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=jms-point-point-ivt-mq-classes

Comment: You can download IBM MQ Advanced for developers for free and run a MQ queue manger for testing. Click the ibm-mq tag and select learn more for links.

Comment: But is there a way to do it via a Maven package? For automated testing running a binary is not really an option, not with the current setup.

Comment: IBM MQ queue managers are not java based.

Answer (score 2):

You can run MQ natively, in a container or in the cloud. The container option lends itself to automated testing as the set up and start can be automated.

For detailed instructions see https://developer.ibm.com/series/mq-ready-set-connect/